# How can I add Environment Variables in IDEA before running a test?

Tags: shell, intellij-idea

I have a Test::Unit configuration and at runtime, I would like a prompt in which i enter an environment(e.g. platform, staging or production) and the test runs in the specified environment. The related links for all environments are in environments.yml in the codebase

Right now, if I manually add an environment variable called DOMAIN and assign its value to 'platform', the test runs in the specified environment.

To do what I need to do, I have tried the following till now:

- Created a Shell script which sets the DOMAIN env variable
- In Before launch in IDEA, I set it to an external tool.

That tool calls the script created in step 1. A prompt is created and this takes in the environment to run the test. That env is passed as a parameter to the shell script.

The problem is, Idea does not pick up the change. Is there an easy way of doing this?

Comment: Look in "Edit Configurations..." for the specific test configuration.

Comment: I know how to do this manually before running a test, I want to implement a prompt  which pops up before running a specific test, and asks the user, in which env do they want to run the test. The tool will set the environment variable behind the scenes.

Comment: Why do it that way? If you have a configuration per environment, the issue is moot.

Comment: I wanted to put this as a setting and make it available to everyone. So, people dont have to worry about env variable. They just enter env in a box and the test works.

Comment: So you make it part of a run configuration setting you distribute to everyone; folks pick the environment they're targeting from the configuration-selection box and the test works.

Comment: Hi Charles, Can you please guide me on how to do this? I researched on  Google and did not get a clear idea on how to do it.